# Flutter How can i clip half of my circle on border?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I have a bordered container. I want to add a half circle and make it looks like clipped as a coupon. But i cant clip my circle as i wanted. I want my circle will be on border so it will look like coupon. But i cant figure out how can i do it.

Its what i wanted :

[image]

Its what i did for now :

[image]

If I can clip that circles it will be like how i want but i dont know how can i do it. Its my code for that widget :

```
Container(
      height: 168,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: ColorService.purple,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                ),
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 20,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -10, 0),
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: ColorService.purple,
                    ),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Container(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, 10, 0),
                  width: 20,
                  height: 20,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: ColorService.purple,
                    ),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Thanks for all helps!

Comment: I just add ClipRRect to top and its solved! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include `clipBehavior` on top Container, default is `Clip.none`

```dart
Container(
  height: 168,
  width: double.infinity,
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, //this
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.purple,
```